# How to distinguish negative number from subtraction?

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, math

I want to create a very simple math calculator which could give me results of simple equations, like 5*(5-9).

In the first step I split the equation into meaningful tokens, eg.:

```
5
*
(
5
-
9
)
```

Now how can I (algorithmically) tell the difference between a negative number (eg. -5) and subtraction (x - 5)?

Edit: I won't have variables (like x) in my equations but I can have functions (like sin, abs).

Comment: you have tagged 2 languages, which language do you want the solution in?

Comment: @mega6382 either is fine

Comment: If there isn't a number before the minus, then it's a negative number. Unless you want to allow equations like `5 * (x - 5)`. However, since SO isn't a free coding service, I'll leave the coding to you. Make some attempt and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: @Tom Do you intend to use some value of x or just have it as x-5?

Comment: @Highdef I won't have variables, so it will be a number, something in brackets or a function

Comment: @MagnusEriksson (5) - 5. There isn't a number before - 5 but it's not a negative number.

Comment: @Tom It depends. You still need to solve the parentheses first, so it should translate to `5-5`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's the problem I have. I can't figure out the rule since there are so many cases. And even things like 5 + -5 are valid after all.

Comment: @Tom You can make use of stack approach by pushing the tokens in array. Give the brackets precedence and then /, * , + , - and so on. First, compute and solve the equation within the brackets and then replace the bracket solution  in the main equation.

Comment: @Highdef I am going to use Reverse Polish Notation to compute the whole thing but first I need to figure out if -5 is one token or 2 tokens (- and 5).

Comment: Oh, for that you can make use of this logic. Suppose, you have these 2 equations: i. 5+ -5 and ii. 5 - 5. I guess that's the problem you're dealing with but I hope you know that the negative sign would be the only anomally. To solve this, check the current token if its a symbol, check the next token also. If its a symbol(i.e '-'), then the next value is negative following it. If not, then its a subtraction.. So, since the first equation, 5+ -5, when the current symbol + is encountered and the next token is also a symbol, we consider the number following it as negative.

Comment: A yet simple solution to it would be to develop a function that provides the alternative of 'transforming' the symbols. Eg, if the current token is '+' and next is '-', replace the +- with -. If the current is '-' and next is also '-', then replace the -- with +.

Comment: @Highdef But there are also functions to consider, eg. sin(-5) and 5 + 6 * -5^22.

Comment: Actually `-1^2` is a simple edge case that people disagree on. I think there are widely used spreadsheets that return 1, while others return -1.

Comment: @Tom Like I said about the negatation problem you're facing you could make use of what I stated before. And considering the functions, suppose, Sin(-5). You would need to make use of functions while checking each and every token i.e if a Sin, Cos, tan,etc is encountered then take the value following the next opening bracket and compute it until it is closed. You can make use of a opencounter for that. After what is inside the bracket is computer in this case, -5, solve Sin of (-5). Like I said before, each and every operator needs to have a precedence and associativity. Not a simple calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
<?php
function splitEq($a) {
    $split = array();

    // count al the minuses:
    $c = substr_count($a, "-");

    // when 0, its save!
    if ($c == 0) {
        // split string in chars:
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($a); $i++) $split[] = substr($a, $i, 1);

        return $split;
    } else {
        // check them:
        $offset = 0;
        $good = 0;

        //  loop through the minuses:
        for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
            $p = strpos($a, "-", $offset);

            // before there is a number == good
            if ($p > 0) {
                if (is_numeric(substr($a, $p - 1,1))) $good++;
            }
            $offset = $p + 1;
        }

        // everything is good, no negative numbers:
        if ($good == $c) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($a); $i++) $split[] = substr($a, $i, 1);

            return $split;
        } else {
            // split needs a bit of special attention:
            $split = array();
            $ex = explode("-", $a);

            // loop through all the parts

            // make the array:
            for ($y = 0; $y < strlen($a); $y++) $split[] = substr($a, $y, 1);

            // calculate the offset
            $o = strlen($ex[0]);
            for ($i = 1; $i < count($ex); $i++) {
                // if the previous $i is empty, then add it to the first item.
                if ($ex[$i - 1] == "") {
                    array_splice($split, 0,1);
                    $split[0] = "-" . $split[0];
                }

                // if the previous last char is not numeric
                $last = substr($ex[$i - 1], -1, 1);
                if (!is_numeric($last) AND $last) {
                    array_splice($split, $o, 1);
                    $split[$o] = "-" . $split[$o];
                }
                // update offset
                $o += strlen($ex[$i]);

            }
            return $split;
        }
    }
}

$ex[0] = "abs(5*-9)";
$ex[1] = "5*(1-9)";
$ex[2] = "-1*(5-9)";
$ex[3] = "5*(-1-9)";
$ex[5] = "-3+2(-5-9)";
$ex[6] = "5*3";
$ex[7] = "5*(-1-9)";


foreach($ex as $e) {
    echo "<h2>" . $e . "</h2>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(splitEq($e));
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

There are some limitations; you can't use double digits like `15` at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, if the previous token is something that can be subtracted from then it will be subtraction, otherwise it is negation.

Comment: How can I tell it can be subtracted?

Comment: Negation is also a form of subtraction (-5 = 0-5)

Comment: You should evaluate the previous token and determine this. Usually numbers and variables are the only things that are subtractable. Something like `if (isSubtractable(prevToken)) { ... }`